# Scroll smoothly on hover an unordered list with fixed height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fixed height unordered list `<ul>` with fixed height list items `<li>`

My ul height is 600px and it contains 200 li items with 40px height.

I need to create a script which scrolls down the list when the mouse hovers the bottom of the list and scrolls up when the mouse hovers the top of the list.

I tried this: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverscroll  but it is not as smooth as it should be, so I need to create a custom one (maybe not using jQuery at all).

Any ideas or examples? How can I achieve the desired effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use $wrapper.animate({scrollTop: step});
for example 
JS:

```
var isScroll = false;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#up').hover(function () {
            isScroll = true;
            gotoNext(true);
        }, function () { isScroll = false; });
        $('#down').hover(function () {
            isScroll = true;
            gotoNext(false);
        }, function () { isScroll = false; });
    });

    function gotoNext(dir) {
        if (isScroll) {
            isScroll = true;
            var step = dir ? '-=20' : '+=20';
            $('#wrapper').animate({
                scrollTop: step
            }, 200, "linear");
            setTimeout(function () { gotoNext(dir); }, 200);
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div style="height:10px; background:green; width:200px;" id="up"></div>
<div style="height:200px; overflow:auto; width:200px;" id='wrapper'>
<ul>
<li style="height:30px;">1</li>
<li style="height:30px;">2</li>
<li style="height:30px;">3</li>
<li style="height:30px;">4</li>
<li style="height:30px;">5</li>
<li style="height:30px;">6</li>
<li style="height:30px;">7</li>
<li style="height:30px;">8</li>
<li style="height:30px;">9</li>
<li style="height:30px;">1</li>
<li style="height:30px;">2</li>
<li style="height:30px;">3</li>
<li style="height:30px;">4</li>
<li style="height:30px;">5</li>
<li style="height:30px;">6</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="height:10px; background:green; width:200px;"  id="down"></div>
```

it is looks pretty good for me

Answer (score 0):

Why not devide your screen into a grid? once the mouseX and mouseY hit the top grid it will scroll up with a predefined integer value

Comment: What do you mean with divide into a grid? My biggest concern is about scrolling smoothly...  how can it be done?

Comment: That is a very broad question actually if I would do that same I would define a div and assign it a class then after that I would use Javascript to detect if my mouse is currently hitting the top div if so It scrolls up if not the page remains just how it is. (same for bottom)