# JQuery scroll on hover or mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery with thumbnails inside a container with `overflow:hidden` which I need to scroll. I already have it scrolling in steps on click, using `.scrollLeft()`. How to make it scroll smoothly on `mouseover`, or preferably on `mousedown` to the end of list? I'm looking for a way without plugins.

This is what I got for scroll on click.

```
$("#slider").scrollLeft($("#slider").scrollLeft() + 200);
```

Comment: _"I'm looking for a way without plugins."_ --> You're using jQuery...

Comment: I answered to similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108242/scroll-smoothly-on-hover-an-unordered-list-with-fixed-height/10109044#10109044 it is about vertical scroll but main idea is clear

Comment: @Cerbrus Mostly people refer to jQuery as a library, and the little patches and extensions people come up with as plugins.

Comment: @IgorCh thanks for the link! I actually tried doing something similar, but it for some reason it jumps in distinctive steps rather then smoothly... Im trying to figure what I did differently

Comment: @IgorCh Got it, I was missing "linear" arg in animation. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like:

```
$("#someEle").hover(function(){
    $("#slider").scrollLeft($("#slider").scrollLeft() + 200);
},function(){
    $("#slider").stop();
});
```

Comment: It just jumps once by a step. Is there a way to smoothly scroll until the end of inner div?